# Approach for a queue in Ecommerce site with limited product inventory

Tags: e-commerce, queue, inventory

I am looking to implement the following;

For an Ecommerce platform build with Ruby on Rails, it is likely that there will be a situation where many people are trying to buy a product while there is limited stock. E.g. product X which will become available today at 13:00 has 100 items in stock. At 13:00 however 300 people come to the website and try to buy product X.

For these type of situations; what is the correct approach/best practice to implement a queue? What kind of technology is used? Is this possible with RoR?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use inventory locking system.
study out how Magento ( PHP based ecommerce open source ) handle all these things.
better to use Magento fro E-Commerce application. try it out once.

get back to me if you need further help.